# Syntax for more than 2 possibilities to a condition in C?

Tags: c

Say I have a condition with 2 possibilities: a <= 10 and a > 10.  I can use the if...else statement to printf() output 1 if a <= 10 or output 2 if a > 10.

But if I have a condition with 3 possibilities (like a <= 10, 10 < a <= 20, and a > 20) how do I write the program to printf() output 1 if a <= 10, output 2 if 10 < a <= 20, or output 3 if a > 20?

Comment: `if (..) {printf("1\n");} else if (..) {printf("2\n");} else {printf("3\n");}`; fill in the dots with the appropriate conditions. Note that the form presented does *not* have the dots for the `a > 20` clause, as that is covered in the else.

Comment: Fixed options to remove "gaps" such as `a == 10`.

Comment: You can still use an `if...else` statement.

Answer (score 4):

You just nest them, something like:

```
if ( a < 10) {
    printf("1\n");
} else {
    if (a < 20) {
        printf("2\n");
    } else {
        printf("3\n");
    }
}
```

or, provided the `if` statements are the *only* things nested, you can get rid of quite a few braces:

```
if ( a < 10)
    printf("1\n");
else if (a < 20)
    printf("2\n");
else
    printf("3\n");
```

Comment: I almost never move the if *inside* the else, unless it adds value in context. My brain reads it more clearly as an aligned "else if".

Comment: @user2864740 That is certainly the preferable solution. However, nesting is certainly the obvious solution until one is aware of the syntactic sugar of `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use an `if...else` statement. The most obvious solution is to nest another `if` in the `else` clause. You can add a forth condition by nesting an `if...else` instead.

This is so common that most languages provide an `else if` option in order to avoid deep nesting when there are many possible conditions.

Comment: Well, technically, there is no "else if" option in C, it's just the ability to not need braces if there's only _one_ statement in the block. But I see where you're coming from.